Exercise on self-adjointness of Hamiltonian
I am struggling with some exercise I have to solve for my quantum mechanics class.

PROBLEM:
Suppose $|\psi\rangle, |\phi\rangle$ are normalised and linearly independent (but not necessarily orthogonal) states and $|\Gamma\rangle$ is a state vector orthogonal to both $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\phi\rangle$ in a three dimensional complex Hilbert space.
Suppose further that the Hamiltonian $H$ acts on the states as follows:
$$H |\psi\rangle = k |\phi\rangle \quad , \qquad H |\phi\rangle = k^{\ast} |\psi\rangle \quad , \qquad H |\Gamma\rangle = 0 \quad . \tag{1}$$
What are the conditions that $|\psi\rangle, |\phi\rangle$ must satisfy in order for $H$ to be self-adjoint?

ATTEMPT: I first of all want to find the matrix representation of $H$. As far as I know, the identity
$$\langle m| H |n\rangle = H_{mn}$$
for the $m$-th and $n$-th basis vector only holds if the basis is an ONB.
[Question 1: Is this correct? Does the identity hold for every basis, for every orthogonal basis or for ONBs only? ]
Although $|\psi\rangle, |\phi\rangle$ are not necessarily orthogonal, they are still linearly independent and thus the set $|\psi\rangle, |\phi\rangle, |\Gamma\rangle$ forms a basis. Using equation (1), the matrix representation may still be found to be
$$ (H_{ij}) = \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & k^{\ast} & 0 \\ k & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right]$$
which gives the correct results as can be easily checked for $|\psi\rangle = (1,0,0)^T$, for $ |\phi\rangle = (0,1,0)^T$ and for $|\Gamma\rangle = (0,0,1)^T$. HOWEVER, this matrix is already self-adjoint. I assume that I am missing or misunderstanding something here since the exercise specifically asks for conditions on the states.
[Question 2: What conditions on $|\psi\rangle, |\phi\rangle$ for $H$ to be self-adjoint am I missing here? ].

EDIT: After checking the comments, I would approach the problem as follows: Using the definition of self-adjoint operator, I have
$$\langle \psi | H^{\dagger} \psi \rangle = \langle H \psi | \psi \rangle = \big( H | \psi \rangle \big)^{\dagger} | \psi \rangle = k^{\ast} \langle \phi | \psi \rangle$$
but also
$$\langle \psi | H \psi \rangle = k \langle \psi | \phi \rangle $$
and so in order for $\langle \psi | H^{\dagger} \psi \rangle = \langle \psi | H \psi \rangle$ to hold (assuming $k \in \mathbb{C}$ and $|\psi\rangle, |\phi \rangle$ not orthogonal), one must have
$$\langle \psi | \phi \rangle = k^{\ast}$$
Is this correct?

So you work with a three-dimensional (complex) Hilbert space?!

Yes, thank you, I added this detail to the question.

your matrix realization is not correct.  You need to expand on an orthonormal basis, just just linearly independent vectors.  Moreover, it is simpler to use the definition of self-adjoint rather than find a matrix representation.

Could you elaborate on why my matrix is wrong? Using the matrix on the basis vectors (1,0,0) and (0,1,0) and (0,0,1) gives the desired results. Wouldnt that mean that the matrix must be correct? Please tell me if my reasoning using the definition is correct: $\langle \psi | H^{\dagger} \psi \rangle = \langle H \psi | \psi \rangle = k^{\ast} \langle \phi | \psi \rangle$ which by self-adjointness should be equal to $\langle \psi | H \psi \rangle = k \langle \psi | \phi \rangle$ and therefore $\langle \psi | \phi \rangle = k^{\ast}$?

What does "ONB" stand for?  I have a guess but I've never seen the acronym before.

@MichaelSeifert orthonormal basis. It is commonly used in german books, maybe one does not use it in english ones.

What is $H\phi$ in (1)?

@Octavius in your reply, you are using orthonormal vectors.  However, in your question, $\langle \phi\vert\psi\rangle\ne 0$ (or at least not necessarily $0$).

Hm, in my reply I deduced that $\langle \psi | \phi \rangle =k^{\ast}$ and therefore not orthonormal. I incorporated this approach into the question under the item "EDIT". Please tell me what you think.

If you have $|\psi\rangle = (1,0,0)^T$, for $ |\phi\rangle = (0,1,0)^T$ then clearly $\langle \phi\vert\psi\rangle=0\ne k^*$.

Thanks to @ZeroTheHero who brought me onto the right track, I was able to find the solution to the problem myself.
The Hamiltonian with respect to the basis $\{ | \psi \rangle, |\phi \rangle, |\Gamma\rangle\}$ is indeed given by the matrix
$$ (H_{ij}) = \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 & k^{\ast} & 0 \\ k & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right]$$
However, the property that the adjoint matrix coincides with the transposed conjugate matrix ($H_{mn}^{\dagger} = H_{nm}^{\ast}$) only holds with respect to an orthonormal basis (ONB). It is therefore not obvious whether the above matrix is self-adjoint. In order to check self-adjointness of the given Hamiltonian, the following steps may be carried out
$$\langle \psi | H^{\dagger} \psi \rangle = \langle H \psi | \psi \rangle = \big( H | \psi \rangle \big)^{\dagger} | \psi \rangle = k^{\ast} \langle \phi | \psi \rangle \overset{!}{=} \langle \psi | H \psi \rangle = k \langle \psi | \phi \rangle $$
and so in order for $\langle \psi | H^{\dagger} \psi \rangle = \langle \psi | H \psi \rangle$ to hold (assuming $k \in \mathbb{C}$), one may have
$$ \boxed{\langle \psi | \phi \rangle = k^{\ast}}$$

My initial approach was to try and find the matrix representation of the Hamiltonian. In order to check the above result, this is (correctly) redone below:
Assuming that $|\psi \rangle$ and $|\phi \rangle$ are not orthogonal, the vector
$$| \sigma \rangle := \frac{1}{\| \sigma \|} \Big( | \phi \rangle - \langle \psi | \phi \rangle | \psi \rangle \Big)$$
is constructed such that the set $\{ |\psi \rangle, |\sigma \rangle, |\Gamma \rangle \}$ forms an ONB. With the shorthand notation $\ell := \langle \psi | \phi \rangle$ the matrix with respect to this ONB is:
$$ (H_{ij}) = \left[ \begin{matrix} k\ell & \frac{k^{\ast} - k \ell^2}{\sqrt{1-|\ell|^2}} & 0 \\ k\sqrt{1-|\ell|^2} & -k \ell & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right]$$
Then $H_{ij} = H_{ji}^{\ast}$ holds if $(k\ell)^{\ast} = k\ell$ which coincides with the results obtained before.
